# Pass Parameters to stored procedure from asp.net and the display the results on a GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to pass parameters from asp.net to my stored procedure. The parameters would be the value selected from the dropdownlists and then get data back from the stored procedure and display on a Gridview in asp.net when the user clicks the submit button on the webpage. When I click on the submit button nothing the gridview doesn't pop up. I am stuck on this for a while now. An exception pops up by the Fill method when I try to debug it saying I need to pass parameters. The exception is copied below.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'Submit' expects parameter '@Address', which was not supplied.'

Below is my stored procedure

```
USE [Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [Submit]
@Address varchar(12),
@Number varchar(5),
@Name varchar(24),
@Type varchar(3)
as 
begin
    select a.*, b.*
    from Employee as a
    inner join Department as b
    on a.Number = b.Number
    where a.Address = @Address and a.Number = @Number and a.name = @Name and b.Type = @Type 
end
```

Below is my .cs code

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string s = "Submit";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Submit";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the DataAdapter with only the string `s` instead of with your SqlCommand `cmd`:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
```

[Create it with the command instead.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You must not have done it right.   Follow the example in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
  dt.Load(reader);
}

GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.Databind():
```